# Existence of a normal subgroup in a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. If a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is contained in the centre, then does there exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, such that $P \cap N = \{e\}$ and $PN=G$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear deibor, I believe that the answer is *yes*, by Schur--Zassenhaus, but what is the context?  Do you just want to have a yes/no answer citing a rather powerful theorem? Or is this an exercise you want to solve using some prescribed set of tools and methods?  Regards,

Comment: Isn't this the exercise from Herstein's Topics in Algebra (ex. 16, from the Sylow theory part (2.12))? I never figured out a proof that didn't use Burnside's transfer theorem (or Schur-Zassenhaus). If $P$ is central, it is central in its normalizer, thus has a normal complement by that theorem. I wonder if there is an intended elementary proof that uses only Sylow theory.

Comment: MATT: If it is yes, then I want to know how to construct such $N$. Also it is not an exercise. I,m just curios to know, since i can't find a counter example. Thank you.

Comment: Mikko Korhonen; What you said is true, i have checked just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, by Schur--Zassenhaus.  The point is that $P$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ which is also central in $G$, and thus is normal in $G$, while $G/P$ is of coprime order in $G$ (because $P$ is a $p$-Sylow).

(As Mikko Korhonen noted above in comments, the [Burnside transfer theorem](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_normal_p-complement_theorem) can be used instead.)